# When Should You Add Methods To A Private Interface?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

So I've recently been using more private interfaces in my classes.  I've been leaving the stuff that is needed by other classes in the .h (public), and then keeping all other methods in the private interface in the .m.  My question is, I don't see any reason to keep any methods in my private interface as the app works fine without this.  What is really the point?  Any why aren't system methods like viewDidLoad in the private interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I've recently been using more private interfaces in my classes. I've been leaving the stuff that is needed by other classes in the .h (public), and then keeping all other methods in the private interface in the .m.

That's perfect. In some cases, you will want to use naming conventions or prefixes to avoid naming collisions. Moving on…

> My question is, I don't see any reason to keep any methods in my private interface as the app works fine without this. What is really the point?

[**Encapsulation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29). Hide your data and implementation from your clients (and even subclasses) in order to minimize the side effects of any changes you must make. If the client really only needs 3 methods in the public interface -- declare only those 3 methods. Keep the remainder of the implementation details private to the class. When you don't use this, mutant implementations tend to multiply where clients use these unnecessary methods. Which means that when you need to change something, you will have a ton of detail to review across several source files (and apps, if you write libraries). A class' public interface is a good area to focus on being minimal.

> Any why aren't system methods like viewDidLoad in the private interface?

`viewDidLoad` was *designed* to be overridden by subclasses, where necessary. Its declaration is public for 2 primary reasons:

- Documentation. Your implementations will need this initialization step, and you need to know how to override it correctly.
- So you can write `[super viewDidLoad]`, and the compiler can be assured you are doing the right thing. If `UIViewController` had not declared it as an instance method, there would be at least one compiler warning.

Comment: yes, i realize rmaddy's answer is very different. based on the wording of the OP, it seems that the OP was not actually asking (solely) about declarations in an `@interface` scope.

Answer (score 3):

Adding method declarations in a private category is obsolete with the latest LLVM compiler. It used to be that methods had to be implemented in the proper order or you could add method declarations in a private category in the .m file. The latest compiler precludes the need for this. The new compiler does a 2-pass compile so it knows about all methods.

So the short answer to your question is - never. :)

Edit: Here's some sample code to reflect the ongoing discussion to this answer:

In the .h file:

```
// Only public stuff here
@interface Foo
- (void)somePublicMethod;
@end
```

In the .m file:

```
// private additions - clients don't need to know about this stuff
@interface Foo () <UIActionSheetDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic) UIPickerView *pickerView; // private property
@end

@implementation Foo {
    UIActioSheet *_myActionSheet; // private ivar
}

- (void)somePrivateMethod {
    [self anotherPrivateMethod]; // yeah - I can call methods further down in the class
}

- (void)anotherPrivateMethod {
}
@end
```

Comment: Apple uses LLVM?  Clearly I'm behind the curve.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Only for the last two years (give or take).

Comment: So I don't have to declare methods in the headers of my classes unless an external class needs to act on it?

Comment: .h files are needed only when a class needs to reference another class so the first class can know about its public interface. Since no class is only used by itself, you still end up with a .h for the class declaration.

Comment: Ya but I mean if I have a method [self doSomething]; in a class that is only called within that class, do I need to declare the method anyhwere?

Comment: No, just provide the implementation and you are good. You never needed a separate declaration for private methods as long as they were in an appropriate order in the .m file. The new compiler simply removes the need for a specific order.

Comment: so what about private properties.  Is that the only reason to use a private interface in the .m?

Comment: Yes, private properties are a good reason to use private interface (actually, it's called a class extension or a private category). It also useful for declaring that the class adheres to various protocols without the need to state so in the public interface.

Comment: @rmaddy, aren't class extensions also unnecessary now? Can't you just put curly braces after '@ implementation' in the .m file now to declare private properties or ivars?

Comment: You can (and I do) declare private ivars in the curly braces of the @implementation. But you still use the class extension (private @interface) to declare private properties and specify adherence to any protocols you might use.